# MySQL and PHP databases?

Tags: php, mysql, database

I am doing an exercise with PHP and MySQL database management, and I'm trying to return an amount from a field in a table with PHP. I am trying to get the value from the CalsPerServ in the foods table where the foodsID is equal to the foodsID the user has selected. All I'm getting now though is an array, when I should be returning one result. Any idea what went wrong?

```
if($tableName == "meals"){
        $foodsID = filter_input(INPUT_POST, "foodsID");
        $servings = filter_input(INPUT_POST, "Servings");
        $foodsID = mysql_real_escape_string($foodsID);
        $servings = mysql_real_escape_string($servings);

        $query = "SELECT CalsPerServ FROM foods WHERE foodsID=$foodsID";
        $result = mysql_query($query, $connect);
        $CalsPerServ = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);

        print $CalsPerServ;

        $calories = ($CalsPerServ * $servings) * 100;

        $sql .= "(foodsID, Servings, Calories) VALUES ('$foodsID', '$servings', '$calories')";

        $sqltwo = "INSERT INTO daily_diary (foodsID, CaloriesPlus) VALUES ('$foodsID', '$calories')";
        $resulttwo = mysql_query($sqltwo, $connect);
}
```

Comment: mysql_fetch_assoc returns an associative array. And tell your teacher that mysql_* is deprecated. (http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-assoc.php)

Comment: -0.49 for using `mysql_query` in 2013.  Take a look at mysqli or PDO.  Either one supports prepared statements, which for one thing means you don't have to do all this manual escaping crap and cobbling together SQL by hand.

Comment: @Tom Tell me about it... I'm annoyed it's all he teaches!

Comment: **+1** for learning process. You're a lot further than I am right now. And whoever minused 1 you, shame shame.

Comment: @cHao Really, trust me, I wouldn't be doing databases at all if this weren't for school!

Comment: @RachelleBennington Don't mention it, you're welcome. I'm just getting into SQL myself and know how hard it can be. Although, I should've stuck with **dBase IV**, way back when and kept going. Enjoy the adventure, cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem lies here in this line

```
$calories = ($CalsPerServ * $servings) * 100;
```

`$CalsPerServ` is an array containing the result from the query. In order to get single column value out of it you have to use it like this

```
$calories = ($CalsPerServ['CalsPerServ'] * $servings) * 100;
```

Comment: Ah! Thank you so much! I knew there was some little thing I wasn't doing. I guess my brain is fried after 8 hours of coding!

Comment: @RachelleBennington it happens mostly with the programmers :)

Answer (score 1):

Even though you are querying for one thing, mysql_fetch_assoc() returns an array.

This way even if you have selected more than one thing, you will always know you will get back an associative array, with the selected items as its keys.

```
$CalsPerServ = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);

 print $CalsPerServ['CalsPerServ'];
```

Comment: Ah! Thank you so much! I knew there was some little thing I wasn't doing. I guess my brain is fried after 8 hours of coding!